# How to check in Google Analytics which device clicked my tracking event?

Tags: events, seo, google-analytics

In my Google analytics account I'm tracking some events from my website using GA `_gaq.push` event. GA tracking report shows total events clicked but it doesn't shows via which device that event had been clicked. Even in GA->Audience->Mobile->Devices section only shows which devices visit the page but it doens't give the report which device clicked the event.

Basically I need categorze the trackevent to PC and Mobile clicks. I know this can be done via php appending some text to trackevent if this click from mobie site. eg:

```
<?php
  if($mobileSite){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'opt_label_m', opt_value_m]);
  }else{
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'opt_label', opt_value]);
  }

?>
```

I need to know is GA already doing this job for tracking events ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Advanced Segment" has a pre-defined "Mobile Traffic" segment. If you apply that and look at your event reports you'll see only events triggered by mobile devices (likewise you can create an "not mobile traffic" segment and apply both segments, which gives you a compare view between the two).

**Updated to add**

You can create a custom report to get want you need:

Customization->New Custom Report->Dimension "Mobile Device Branding" (or "Device Marketing Name" or "Device Model") -> Metric : Event Value -> Filter "Event Label" (or "Event Category) -> save.

So not a standard report, but it's possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, but is it possible to get the device name the event clicked ?

Comment: Don't think so, but you can additionally segment by OS whicgh at least allows you to see differences for iOS/Android/Windows Phone Users.